# How to start the Berserk manga, should I bother with chapters 000a and 000b?

Tags: berserk

What chapters do the Berserk movies cover? And what are the chapters 000a and 000b and 000c, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The Golden Age arc covers volume 3 to 14, starting with "Golden Age" and ending on "He who hunts Dragons."

[Chapter 0](http://berserk.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_00) is the "draft" of what is now the main series, that the author did in college and is considered **non-canon**.

Answer (score 2):

The Berserk movies cover up to Chapter 102. I don't know what "000a" and "000b" but you probably should read them because here's the content percentage in each format:
Manga = 100%
Anime = 60-65%
Movies = 40%

I've read and watched them all up to said chapters so I was able to make this comparison.